# I think that the Stream.filter() is not showing compile time error even with an invalid predicate

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

In the below code I have this line: `stream.filter(Data::isEven);` 
I am using a `filter()` and a `filter()` accepts a `Predicate` interface as parameter. We all know that `Predicate` has one method with the signature:  `public boolean test(T t);` 
which accepts one parameter and returns a boolean.

I am of the understanding that the `isEven()` method that accepts no parameter is not a valid Predicate because unlike `test()` method it does not take any parameter, so how come my code is not showing a compile time error?

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main App {


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Stream<Data> stream =
                Stream.of(new Data(4), new Data(1));

        stream.filter(Data::isEven); // should throw compile error but doesn't
    }

}


class Data{
    int i;
    public Data(int i) {
        this.i=i;
    }
    public boolean isEven() {
        return i%2==0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any time you see `ClassName::method`, the first parameter gets converted into the target of the method invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data::isEven` is a `Predicate`.

To call this method you have to pass value, like: `myData.isEven()`.
This is the same as it would be `isEven(myData)`. So the difference is only in syntax (parameter either before a dot, or inside parenthesis), but semantically it is the same.

Therefore `isEven` is a `Predicate<Data>` because it accepts `Data` and returns `Boolean`.

Comment: thanks your explanation was helpful. accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that `Data::isEven` is a method reference equivalent to `data -> data.isEven()` predicate :

```
Predicate<Data> predicate = data -> data.isEven();
// is the same as
Predicate<Data> predicate= Data::isEven;
```

This is described in [`JLS 15.13`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) :

> The target reference of an instance method (§15.12.4.1) may be provided by the method reference expression using an `ExpressionName`, a `Primary`, or `super`, or it may be provided later when the method is invoked.
>
> ....
>
> Evaluation of a method reference expression produces an instance of a functional interface type (§9.8). Method reference evaluation does not cause the execution of the corresponding method; instead, this may occur at a later time when an appropriate method of the functional interface is invoked.

In your case `Data::isEven` is a reference to instance method `isEven` of `Data` object.

Comment: isEven() method doesn't match to what the test() method inside that of Predicate interface. What I cannot understand is how is this mismatch being overseen by the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

As others wrote "Data::isEven" or "data -> data.isEven()" is Predicate here. When we invoke *test* method of this predicate, we pass the instance of *data* (you have a stream of such instances) there as a parameter.

Comment: Other answers are constantly updated at high speed. At some moment my answer can lose the sense in such updates :-)